# XMLHttpRequest не работает перебор параметров в JSON

Tags: jquery, json, javascript, xmlhttprequest

Есть файл file.json с таким содержимым:

```
{ 
  "location": "Россия", 
  "language": "Русский"
}
```

Запрос и парсинг производится таким методом:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.overrideMimeType("application/json"); 
xhr.responseType = "json";

xhr.open('GET', '/json/file.json', true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200) {
        var jsonString = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        $('[data-json]').each(
            function() {
                var datajson = $(this).data('json');
                $(this).text(jsonString.datajson);
            }
        )
    }
}
xhr.send(null);
```

Если поэтапно разобрать вывод данных то происходит все таким макаром:

1. В переменной `jsonString` находятся распарсинные данные
2. Потом идет перебор елементов DOM с аттрибутом `data-json`
3. Значение переменной `datajson` равна значению аттрибута `data-json` каждого элемента
4. Ну и в каждый элемент должны подстовлятся данные из файла `file.json`

Не могу найти свою ошибку, почему то если написать так `$(this).text(datajson);` то подставятся значения аттрибута `data-json`. Если написать так `$(this).text(jsonString.location);` то подставится значение параметра `location` из выборки JSON.

Вопрос: как сделать что бы работал такой метод `$(this).text(jsonString.datajson);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(this).text(jsonString[datajson])

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло. Мало знаю про JSON )